# How to get the index value of the current selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML snippet like this in body

```
<div class="screen"></div>
<div class="screen"></div>
```

Now, how should I get each element's index number like this?

```
$(".screen").click(function(){
  // get this element's index() number
})
```

I tried `$(this).index()` but it's returning -1.

Comment: may be you're using jQuery<1.4

Comment: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/mx8Ue/ . According to the spec you'd get -1 if the selector cannot find the element - but you are not using a selector. Is this a complete (minimal) example?

Comment: The index positioning is done related to a group of elements. You are trying to get the index of a single element based on **itself** (instead of a group). Hence, it will return `-1`. I will suggest you to go with `$(this).parent().children().index(this)` or a simple way would be as shown by Arun P Johny in below answer.

Comment: @Mr_Green - The documentation says `$(this).index()` is perfectly legal - *"If no argument is passed [...] the return value is [...] the position of the first element [...] relative to its sibling elements."*, and the demo shows it does work in events. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Please make sure your elements exist at the time of the binding of the event handler - so your code has to be after the divs or wrapped in $(function() {...});

Answer (score 0):

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) documentation

```
$(this).index();
```

Comment: I did but it's returning -1 for all elements

Comment: @AritraHazra make a fiddle

Comment: @AritraHazra try `$(this).index('.screen');`

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4TL9s/)**

Try this ..

```
$(".screen").click(function(){
      // get this element's index() number
        alert($(this).index())
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
$(".screen").click(function(){
 // get this element's index() number
 alert($(this).index())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".screen").click(function(){
      // get this element's index() number
       alert('Index: ' + $('div').index(this));
    })
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EC6b4/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the [third variant of .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)

```
var $screens = $(".screen").click(function(){
  // get this element's index() number
    alert($screens.index(this))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VvMsY/)